# Regression: Estimated Partial Effect of Regressor? (Need help understanding answer)

Tags: regression, linear-regression

1. Estimate a linear regression model for log wages on education, experience, and experience squared. Report Results.
2. Predict the effect on average log wage of increasing everybody's education level by one year.

Hint: If the regression model is
$$
\log (\text { wage })_{i}=\beta_{0}+\beta_{1} \times \text { educ }_{i}+\beta_{2} \times \operatorname{exper}_{i}+\beta_{3} \times \operatorname{exper}_{i}^{2}+\varepsilon_{i}
$$
then the effect of increasing education level of individual $i$ by one year is
$$
\theta_{i}=\beta_{1}-\beta_{2}-\beta_{3} \cdot\left(2 \cdot \operatorname{exper}_{i}-1\right)
$$
because one year additional education implies one year less work experience.

The effect we are interested in is:
$$
\theta=\beta_{1}-\beta_{2}-\beta_{3} \cdot(2 \cdot \overline{\operatorname{exper}}-1)
$$

After you defined this, compare the task to that in lecture 5 where we consider the partial effect in a quadratic model.  In lecture, we saw how this partial effect can be specified as a linear combination of the estimators. I.e. if $c$ is a K x 1 vector of constants then the partial effect can be expressed as a linear combination: $ c' \hat\beta$.  In this regard, please see included answer below.

I do not understand how he came about the vector of constants or the standard error. More specifically, how do you get standard error of .0062 as shown at the very bottom of the answer below?

Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Original regression points are

$$\log (W_i)=\beta_0+\beta_1\text{educ}_i+\beta_2\text{exper}_i+\beta_3(\text{exper}_i)^2+\epsilon_i$$

After giving everyone one more year of education and decreasing experience by one year, we get

$$\log (W_i)=\beta_0+\beta_1(1+\text{educ}_i)+\beta_2(-1+\text{exper}_i)+\beta_3(-1+\text{exper}_i)^2+\epsilon_i$$

The difference between these two is

$$\theta=\beta_1-\beta_2-\beta_3(2\text{exper}_i-1)$$

For all people, we have

$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(\beta_1-\beta_2-\beta_3(2 experi_i-1)}{n}=\beta_1-\beta_2-\beta_3(2\overline{experi}_i-1)$$

Thus the coefficient of $\beta_0$ is 0, beta1 is 1, beta2 is -1, and beta3 is -(2$\overline{experi}$ -1). We get the vector

$$c=(0, 1, -1, -(2\overline{\text{exper}}_i-1))$$

Apparently the vector defined in the lecture has its fourth term to be the negative of the actual coefficient, or is a typo.

To get the estimated effect, plug in the coefficients as well as the average of the experi's for all the n subjects, to get the estimated effect: .0923-.0791-(-.0020)*(2$\overline{exper}_i$-1).

The standard error can be found by the square root of the following variance:

This is equivalent to $$\begin{split}c'Var(\hat\beta)c&=(0, 1, -1, -2\overline{exper}_i+1)'\begin{pmatrix}.2223^2&\sigma_{12}&\sigma_{13}&\sigma_{14}\\\sigma_{21}&.0076^2&\sigma_{23}&\sigma_{24}\\\sigma_{31}&\sigma_{32}&.0249^2&\sigma_{34}\\\sigma_{41}&\sigma_{42}&\sigma_{43}&.0009^2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\-1\\-2\overline{exper}_i+1\end{pmatrix}\end{split}$$

I have never used matlab, but the `LinearModel` object should have a property called `CoefficientCovariance` that has what we need.

Comment: The $\text{Var}(\theta)$ is the step I'm confused with.  In Lecture 5, he goes about deriving the variance of the linear combination $c' \hat\beta$ as $\operatorname{Var}\left(c^{\prime} \hat{\beta}\right)$ = $c^{\prime} \operatorname{Var}(\hat{\beta}) c$. Where did you get that expression for the variance? Also what is $\operatorname{Var}\left(\overline{\text { experi }}_{i}\right)$?

Comment: Think there's a slight error in my post with regards to your comment, $\overline{experi}_i$ should be a constant and no variance. But $c'Var(\hat \beta)c$ should be $.0076^2+.0249^2+.0009^2(4)(2\overline{experi}_i-1)^2$ from the formula $Var(aX+bY)=a^2Var(X)+b^2Var(Y)+2abCov(X,Y)$ (but $Cov(X,Y)=0$ here). See updated post for some more details.

Comment: Fantastic ty! So, average experience here is 13.61176. After plugging that into the formula for the estimated effect: $.0923-.0791-(-.0020)^{*}\left(2 \overline{e x p e r}_{i}-1\right)$ = 0.065647. It seems close enough. But I'm still not able to get the same standard error as in the answer.

Comment: If it helps, here's the matlab output: 

[0 1 -1 -26.2235]*[.0494 0 0 0;0 .000057 0 0;0 0 .000622 0;0 0 0 .00000081]*[0;1;-1;-26.2235] = 0.0012

Comment: Can this have something to do with the fact that we're using a semi-log regression? Doesn't the effect need to be exponentiated? Beyond that, How are we sure the covariances are zero?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting that too as the variance, and square rooted gives $0.03513951$. The only possibilities are there is actually some covariance between the estimates, what I'm doing is wrong, or typo in the answer key. Maybe you could ask the TA. I am not sure if the effect needs to be exponentiated as the response is already in log form, and the fact that you got the ballpark for the estimated effect without exponentiating.

Comment: Now that I ran a toy example in R, it seems that the command in R to find the variance covariance matrix of the estimates is `vcov`. Dunno what the command in matlab is, but after you find that out from the fitted model you can set up the matrix calculations to determine the standard error

Comment: Brilliant. I just used that in R and got the right standard error. TY!

Comment: I have a question regarding an extension of the problem posted [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4119255/wages-regressed-on-education-and-experience-estimate-effect-of-changing-paramet](math.stachexchange.com). Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @aisync Gave it my best shot!